# Over 400 reputation lost overnight

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

Yesterday, I had 1700 reputation on Stack Overflow, but today I only have 1289. Why did this happen?

Comment: I also had this happen on Stack Overflow, sometime in the past week. My rep was just above 8000, now it's back down at 7830. :-(

Answer (score 3):

There are several options not all of them are visible:

**Bounty**
If you assign a bounty to a question you lose the rep immediately. This should be visible in your profile.

**Offensive or Spam flags**
If a question or answer received enough flags, it is deleted and you have a -100 rep penalty. Not sure if this is still visible.

**Reputation recalc**
Not all changes in rep are shown immediately (for example upvotes to deleted questions and answers). They are shown if your rep is recalculated. If you want to know your current reputation and the source. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

**Possible vote fraud**
If there has been some suspicious votes, they will be deleted automatically (for example a single account that dedicates most of the upvotes to your account. This does not mean that you have committed fraud.

**A bug**
Maybe you just found a bug.

And remember you can always contact the SO team if you think the rep loss is suspicious.

Comment: It's #4 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285158?tab=reputation) and you should be able to see why your rep went down.

Comment: I can not see any such info.

Comment: @Pramodh looks like you don't have the same user name on SO. I linked to Pramodh's profile. What happens if you go to SO and then click on your user name at the top, then on the reptutation tab?

Comment: it may be some other pramodh . Here is my link http://stackoverflow.com/users/336940?tab=reputation

Comment: you can use the accounts tab of the profile in the future to access all associated accounts' profiles and avoid this problem.

Comment: The lack of anything obvious in Pramodh's reputation history suggests either a recalc or a retraction by the vote fraud detection system.