# What else but downvote and bounty could reduce reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation

I realized that I have less reputation (in SO) then when I looked before. I figured that someone must have withdrawn his up-vote but I am not sure. Am I right with this theory and how could I track that? (See what question the vote got withdrawn on?)

Comment: If you are only talking about 10 or 20 points then see [Show rep lost or gained from rescinded votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40519/59303) which would make this question a duplicate.

Comment: @Jon: 5 points only.

Comment: Most likely a rescinded question upvote then.

Comment: Yes and this is not visible. I tested it out with two users.

Answer (score 2):

If the reputation loss is unexpected, large (>50) and there is no trace in your profile. Its probably due to a rep recalculation, or the removal of suspicious votes. See also [Over 400 reputation lost overnight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70430/over-400-reputation-lost-overnight).

Smaller changes are probably due to vote or acceptance withdrawal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where can I see the vote withdrawels?

Comment: @Jürgen Hollfelder: Either click the envelope at the top of screen and play with the time filters, or go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation (less pretty, more comprehensive)

Comment: Ok. I tried it. Removed upvotes are not logged. I created a second user. Gave him an upvote on an answer. I could see the upvote points. Then I withdrew the upvote and it disappeared without a trace. It is simply not logged.